# Value not displayed in string array in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have one formula field in Crystal report as given below

```
global numberVar detailLine ;
global stringVar array SummaryArun ;
WhilePrintingRecords ;
Redim Preserve SummaryArun [3] ;  

SummaryArun[1] :="Litres Of Liquid";
SummaryArun[2] :="Litres Of Alcohol";
SummaryArun[3] := "Percentage Strength";
```

I am getting the output of this formula field  as "Percentage Strength", but when I declared another formula field as given below

```
global stringVar array SummaryArun ;
Redim Preserve SummaryArun [3] ;
SummaryArun[3];
```

I am not getting any out for this field.

As per I have delcared it as gloabl array we need to get value of second formula field value as "Percentage Strength".

How can I get the array value in another formula field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first formula:

```
//{@formula_one}

// unless you are using this formula in the second pass (i.e. with summary fields)
// whileprintingrecords is unnecessary; it should always be the first entry if you are going
// to use it
WhilePrintingRecords ;

global numberVar detailLine ;

global stringVar array SummaryArun ;
// you don't need to add the Preserve option unless you are trying to keep existing values
// this doesn't appear to be the case here
Redim SummaryArun [3] ;

SummaryArun[1] := "Litres Of Liquid"; 
SummaryArun[2] := "Litres Of Alcohol"; 
SummaryArun[3] := "Percentage Strength";
```

Change your second formula:

```
//{@Percentage Strength}

// if you are declaring your array WhilePrintingRecords (as you have done in the other formula)
// then you will need to do so when you *use* the variable
WhilePrintingRecords;

global stringVar array SummaryArun;

// you aren't changing the size of the array, so this line isn't necessary
//Redim Preserve SummaryArun [3] ;

SummaryArun[3];
```